# How to create a Global service in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have seen numerous posts about global angular services but none of these seem to be the correct idea of "global". I am wondering if it is possible to create a service which does not need to be imported everywhere it used (i.e. global).

I have a couple of Service modules but the only way I can seem to get them to be recognized on a component is to import it on each component. There must be a way to import it into the App module and have it available everywhere.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I don't think singleton is what I am looking for. The angular doc on singelton services has an example app which has a user.service.ts; and to use it they import it to all the modules which require it. Exactly what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: Did you even read the documentation? What you explain is one way to do it. Other is to declare `root` for the value of `@Injectable()`. So what you're looking for is using `providedIn`

Comment: Yes, read it. Yes, using @Injectable with providedIn set to root. No, this does not do what I am asking.

Comment: Well, then I don't know what you're looking for. With `providedIn` you don't need to declare it in any of your module.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what global service means, when you import it in the app module as provider it becomes global, meaning that you don't have to  list it in any other modules to use it in any component constructor

Comment: Thank-you, but my question is not what does "global" mean; my question is how do I set it up so that I do not need to import a service on every page.

Comment: yeah, that's the point that I was trying to make, There is no such thing existing,

Comment: Willing to accept the answer is "there is no way to do this"; but difficult to believe that each time you need a "global" service you need to add the same import code to 40+ different files.